# Error al cargar library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38)

Tags: r, rstudio

He instalado el paquete `BiocManager::install("BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38")`,
luego he cargado con `library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38)` y a continuación de ello tengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Loading required package: BSgenome
Loading required package: Biostrings
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘Biostrings’ version 2.68.0 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘Biostrings’ is imported by ‘KEGGREST’ so cannot be unloaded
```

Entonces, he intentado desinstalar y reinstalar Biostrings y KEGGREST, pero no sé qué sucede que no me permite cargar `BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38` y no he tenido éxito. Pido ayuda en esto por favor